# Saving a project using VS2010 Postbuild Events

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dropbox, post-build-event

I'm collaborating on a project with my buddy, and I'm working on most of the code while he does the front-end interfaces/graphics. I would like for him to have access to the project when he needs it (for instance to check up on progress). I read that you can set up a post-build event with VS to save your project to somewhere else (dropbox in that case, and in mine as well), but there's no documentation anywhere on the web (that I could find) detailing how to do this. If anyone knows and can point me in the right direction, that'd be great.

P.S. Is this the place I should be posting this? Please tell me if this ought to be in a different forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use a free online source code repository like CodePlex, GitHub or Visual Studio Online instead?  Then it's properly stored somewhere and versioned.

Comment: The thing I'm looking for though is that I want it to always be at the latest version so that I don't have to think about uploading it every time.

Comment: But does he really need to see whatever random code you have while in you're in the middle of trying to do something having pressed Ctrl+S, or would he rather see the latest stable working code?

Comment: I understand where you are coming from, and I suppose that would be my best option. I'll look into it, thanks